# How to embed an association model form for many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Ruby VersionL 2.0**

**Rails Version: 4.0**

I am having trouble wrapping my head around what I feel should be an easy problem.

I have 2 controllers: `Quizes` and `Questions` that I would like to associate. To do this, I created a model: `assignment`.

**quiz.rb**

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assignments
    has_many :questions, :through => :assignments
end
```

**question.rb**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assignments
    has_many :quizzes, :through => :assignments

    has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**assignment.rb**

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
    belongs_to :quiz
end
```

**assignment migration**

```
class CreateAssignments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :assignments do |t|
      t.integer :quiz_id
      t.integer :question_id

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :assignments, :quiz_id
    add_index :assignments, :question_id
  end

  def down
    drop_table :assignments
  end
end
```

I am pretty new to this, but I think I followed [the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) correctly. My question now is, How do I actually make this work for a user. I would like the user to be able to see a list of all questions when creating or editing a quiz, and to be able to check a box for each question they would like to associate with the quiz. is this possible?

**Update 1**
(What I have so far)

**/views/quizzes/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@quiz) do |f| %>
  <% if @quiz.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@quiz.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this quiz from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @quiz.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </div>

  <%= fields_for :questions do |quiz_question| %>
    <% @questions.each do |question| %>
      <%= quiz_question.label question.text %>
      <%= check_box_tag :question, question.id %><br>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy. You can implement this functionality in few steps.

Assign `@questions` variable in `new` and `edit` actions in `QuizzesController`.

Show these questions as checkbox in your quiz form:

```
<%= form_for(@quiz) do |f| %>
  # rest of the code...
  <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <p>
      <%= check_box_tag 'quiz[question_ids][]', question.id,
                        @quiz.questions.include?(question) %>
      <%= question.name # or whatever the property is %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Permit `question_ids` param in `QuizzesController`:

```
def quiz_params
  params.require(:quiz).permit(question_ids: [], # rest of the permitted params)
end
```

Thats all.

Comment: Nailed it. I was making this WAY harder than it had to be.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like the user to be able to see a list of all questions when creating or editing a quiz, and to be able to check a box for each question they would like to associate with the quiz. Is this possible?

This is possible, it's simply a matter of deciding what question you would like to display (along with questions already associated with an existing quiz i.e. (when editing), it seems like you would like to have *suggested* questions pop up which arent already associated. Particularly in the case of a newly created quiz with none yet associated).  Then simply, creating an according `Assignment` object in your data base.

Comment: I understand the logic behind this, I think... But I don't fully understand the implementation. Would a `fields_for :assignment` inside of `Quiz.new` be the way to go about this? And then pass something like `@questions = Question.all`?

Comment: Almost, `form_for @quiz` (where `@quiz` was retrieved from you database or `@quiz = Quiz.new`) with a nested `fields_for @quiz.questions` should work. There are couple ways to approach the front-end html form which ultimately gets submitted but that should work.  Also, keep in mind `Question.all` may get pretty large as your database grows.

Comment: `<%= fields_for @quiz.questions do |quiz_question| %>` is throwing this error: `undefined method model_name for #<Class:0x007fda191b3398>` any ideas?

Comment: Try `<%= fields_for Question do |quiz_question| %>` and `<%= fields_for :questions do |quiz_question| %>`, do either of those work?

Comment: Yes, that seemed to work. though this still does not seem to be associating the questions with the quiz the way I had hoped. You can see my form in the update to my question. any ideas?